# How can I retrieve the Top N records from a query?

Tags: mysql, oracle

For example, what if I wanted to retrieve the first 3 records from my query results. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `limit` in MySQL: `select * from your_table order by some_column limit 3` But this only makes sense in combination with a sort order. Otherwise the result could be different every time you execute the query

Comment: Your tags are confusing. Are you looking for an SQL statement in MySQL or in Oracle dbms? PL/SQL is a programming language in Oracle dbms and is not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where rownum <=3;
```

If ordering is considered then

```
select * from 
  (select * FROM table1 order by column_name)
 where rownum <=3;
```

But wait, how this question is related to Oracle and MySql at the same time? Anyways, this will work in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (works on db2 sql):

```
     select * from <table_name> fetch first 3 rows only with ur;
```

Regards